Bound a rational function on $\mathbb{R}$
Let $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$.
Then I want to prove that there is an $R>0$, such that
\begin{align}
\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}~ \Bigl|~x\left(\frac{d^k}{dx^k}f(x)\right)~\Bigr|~\leq R^k.
\end{align}
I tried writing with cauchy integral
$$\frac{d^k}{x^k}f(x)=\frac{k!}{2πi}\oint \frac{\frac{z}{1+z^2}}{(z-x)^{k+1}}dz,$$ but this does not help.
Intuitively this should be true as we always get a polynomial of higher degree without zeros in the denominator. I would appreciate any help :)

Have you tried working out a few derivatives of $f$ and looking for a possible inductive pattern? Certainly using the derivative of a quotient rule, the denominator looks like $(1 + x^2)^{2k}$, hence is a polynomial of degree $4k$ (with roots $x = \pm i$, each multiple times). Can you perhaps show the degree of the numerator is less than $4k-1$? If so, you should be able to proceed with a fairly coarse estimate.

I tried to compute a few derivatives, but don't see any pattern. The numerator always is a polynomial of degree $k+2$. So we clearly have $k+2<4k-1$, but I don' see why this suffices.

The result is not true as $$\begin{align}
\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}~ \Bigl|~x\left(\frac{d^k}{dx^k}f(x)\right)~\Bigr|~\geq \frac{k!}{2^{(k+1)/2}}.
\end{align}$$ for infinitely many $k$ and $\frac{k!}{2^{(k+1)/2}}$ is not $O(R^k)$ for any real $R>0$.
Note that $$\frac{x}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{x-i}+\frac{1}{x+i})$$
Hence $$\frac{d^k}{dx^k}f(x)=\pm \frac{k!}{2}(\frac{1}{(x-i)^{k+1}}+\frac{1}{(x+i)^{k+1}})$$
$$|x\left(\frac{d^k}{dx^k}f(x)\right)|=\frac{k! |x\Re (x+i)^{k+1}|}{(x^2+1)^{k+1}}$$
Note that for $x=1$ one has $(1+i)^{k+1}=2^{(k+1)/2}e^{\pi i (k+1)/4}$ so if $k+1=4m$  one has $|\Re (x+i)^{k+1}|=|(x+i)^{k+1}|=2^{(k+1)/2}$ so $$|x\left(\frac{d^k}{dx^k}f(x)\right)|_{x=1, k=4m+3}=\frac{k!}{2^{(k+1)/2}}$$  so the claim above is proved and the OP result is false.
The above clearly shows how to go about and obtain a uniform bound in $k$ for the expression in the OP but such will involve $k!$ so will be superexponential.

Oh thank you for this computation. It seems like we get $$|x(\frac{d^k}{dx^k})f(x)|\leq R^k *k!$$

Note that $f(z) = z/(1+z^2)$ is a rational function with poles at $z = \pm i$.
The Taylor series $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(x)}{k!} t^k = f(x+t)$$
has radius of convergence $r = \min(|x+i|,|x-i|)$.  So for any $x$,
$\limsup_{k \to \infty} |f^{(k)}(x)| |t|^k/k! = \infty$ if $|t| > r$.
In particular, if $|t| > r$,
$|f^{(k)}(x)| > k! |t|^{-k}$ for infinitely many $k$, and this grows faster as $k \to \infty$ than any $R^k$.
